# how to add a row in an html table that is an <a/> tag holding a URL using asp.net?

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net

I wasn't sure how to phrase this, so let me explain further...
I have an html table in which every row is clickable using this:

```
                $(document).ready(function () {

                $('#mytable tr').click(function () {
                    var href = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
                    if (href) {
                        window.location = href;
                    }
                });

            });
```

I am using asp.net along with mysql to fill up my table.
Here is that code

```
While reader.Read()
            Dim row As New TableRow
            row.ID = "row_" + count.ToString
            For k = 0 To 10
                Dim c As New TableCell
                If IsDBNull(reader(col_list(k))) Then
                    c.Text = "NEVER CONTACTED"
                    row.Cells.Add(c)
                Else
                    c.Text = reader(col_list(k))
                If c.Text = "True" Then
                    c.Text = "Y"
                ElseIf c.Text = "False" Or c.Text = "" Then
                    c.Text = "N"
                End If

                    row.Cells.Add(c)
                End If

            Next


            Table1.Rows.Add(row)
            count += 1
    End While
```

What I want now, is to add is vb code to add another cell in each row to contain something like this:

```
            <td><a href="takemehere">Edit</a></td>
```

This way, when the user clicks on the row, it will take the user to a specific url.
So, how can add a cell that contains a tag like this?

Comment: Does that click function work? ASP renders ID's differently..

Comment: Yeah, it works for an html table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio not fired up, but from memory, something like this:

```
dim c2 as new TableCell
dim link as new Hyperlink

'set properties on hyperlink -- i think the two you will care about are navigateUrl and Text
link.Text = "Edit"
link.NavigateUrl = "whatever"

c2.Controls.Add(link)
row.Cells.Add(c2)
```

Comment: Even better than what I thought I wanted. THanks a lot Cortright!